# Chef Recipe, iteration over array of attributes and templates variable

Tags: chef-recipe

Attribute

```
default['app_metadata']['metadata'] = {}
```

Role

```
"app_metadata": {
  "metadata": {
    "oes_m1": {
      "app.instance": "oes_m1_instance",
      "app.appname": "oes"
      ".."
    },
    "oes_m2": {
      "app.instance": "oes_m2_instance",
      "app.appname": "oes"
      "xx"
      ".."
    }
  }
}
```

Recipe

```
node['app_metadata']['metadata'].each do |instance_name, content|

  template "#{node['app_metadata']['home']}/#{node['hostname']}.app.#{instance_name}.metadata" do
    source 'app_metadata.erb'
    owner node['app_metadata']['user']
    group node['app_metadata']['group']
    mode '0755'
    variables(
      content_erb: content
    )
    action :create
  end
end
```

Template

```
<% (@content_erb).each do |key, value| -%>
<%= key %>: <%= value %>
<% end -%>
```

I keep getting errors on the iteration on passing the variables to template. Does anyone know how to improve this?

Expect Result

app.oes_m1.metadata file

```
app.instance: oes_m1
app.appname: oes
..
```

app.oes_m2.metadata file

```
app.instance: oes_m2
app.appname: oes
xx
..
```

if more instances

```
key: value
..
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your template has issue. Try updating it to this

`<% @content_erb.each do |key, value| %>

<%= key %>: <%= value %>

<% end %>`